# There are no commands defined in the "location" namespace. when i try to import maxmind database for Ip Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, github, ip

I am trying to get all possible information from the Ip that i receive in request from laravel api.now for that i am using this [library](https://github.com/stevebauman/location).So far it is working greate but when i try to Setting up MaxMind database it is giving me an error which i could'nt seem to solve.

when i try to run `php artisan location:update` command it is giving me an error.
can anyone help me?

here is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the package? `composer require <package-name>` If yes, did you try to run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes, I did attempt to retrieve IP information, and it is providing basic details. However, when it comes to using MaxMind, I have not had any success.

Comment: also check your artisan commands if `location:update` was added. run `php artisan`

Comment: That is not my question. My question is if you installed the package.

Comment: yes, I have installed the package successfully for your second question I have just checked it ,  it's not added to the PHP artisan list.

Comment: Then probably the package was not installed. First confirm that the package was installed, 2nd, run `composer dump-autoload`. Then check again the artisan list

Comment: you might need to run `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I reinstalled the package and ran `composer dump-autoload` but still its was not added to the PHP artisan list again run `php artisan cache:clear` commands but no luck

Comment: i checked the package and see that the command `location:update` was indeed in the src  based on this https://github.com/stevebauman/location/blob/master/src/Commands/Update.php

Comment: You might need to publish the vendor and run the dump-autoload command again. If it still fails, write an issue to their github page.